# How to enter space bar in textbox that accepts only character?

Tags: c#

```
if (!Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar))
{
     e.Handled = true;
     base.OnKeyPress(e);
```

(for example Jonh space Jambo) but it work only johnjambo

Answer (score 1):

Just add one more condition and it should work.

```
&& !char.IsWhiteSpace(e.KeyChar)
```

Your overall code should look like this

```
if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsWhiteSpace(e.KeyChar))
{
    e.Handled = true;
    base.OnKeyPress(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the check for IsWhiteSpace too to the keypress()

Answer (score 0):

e.keychar can be converted in Keys object like this:

```
private void textBox_KeyPress_Event(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
   if (char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) || (Keys)e.KeyChar == Keys.Space)
      e.Handled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (!(Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) || (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back) || Char.IsWhiteSpace(e.KeyChar)))
                    e.Handled = true;
```